# How to sort items in template with <select>/<option> tag in Django based app?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-template-filters

Actually, I`m working on E-commerce App using Django Framework.
Here I integrated 'blog' app. But I faced an issue with sorting my Posts.

```
#views.py
class PostListView(ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'article.html'
paginate_by = 3

def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.order_by('-created_at')
```

Comment: What do you want as output ? Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe,message like 'Items have been sorted'